What requirement set does messageChild method of dialog api support in Office Js Addin for Outlook?
I am developing a javascript addin for Mail. I want to support Mac Classic Client as well. The minimum required api set for messageChild() method of dialog api is listed as Mail 1.9 and Dialog API 1.2 . Does it depend on both or just the Dialog API version?
It is a bit ambiguous as the method seems to work on Mac Classic even though it only has a maximum supported requirement set of Mail 1.8.

This is a good question, we had as well, but end up just checking Dialog API 1.2 at runtime. I believe nobody would answer it here at SO. What I can advise is to use "Open Documentation issue" link from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialog?view=common-js-preview#office-office-dialog-messagechild-member(1) and on GitHub "right" Microsoft person will address your question. When you get your answer, post it back to SO, it might be useful for someone else.

Sure, will revert back once I get an answer
